# Filtered Terminal Console Program

Tags: windows, terminal-emulator

does anyone know of a good Terminal Console program for windows (something like cmder, Tabby, etc) where I can run the command prompt AND (requirement) the console lines can be filtered?

Comment: Filtered based on what? Just some phrase? What should be the expected outcome? Non-matching lines removed from output?

Comment: yes, I left that unmentioned because there are various acceptable ways.. either you could type in a search box and then it would match only those lines... or use a dialog to construct filter keyword / regexes and check/uncheck those.. I mean basically similar to what you'd find in log viewer programs. but the point is to match only specific lines..

Comment: but if they are no such terminal programs that can do this then just one that lets you search the console output would be fine